# Javascript works on 1st page but not the second

Tags: javascript, html

After several years of using Jquery I have decided to learn at least basic Javascript. I have run into what is to me a strange problem.

If I have a script like this that runs on page 1, but do not have the same class's on page 2, all scripts stop running that come after this script.

```
var numberOfClasses = document.querySelectorAll("li.line");
document.querySelector("p.classes").innerHTML = 'Number of support Links ' + numberOfClasses.length;
```

If I do not have the `"p.classes"` on the second page, nothing in the JavaScript file that comes after code that will run. Is this normal? The code is in a JS file that is included at the bottom of the html file on both pages. The code above is for example only

The error message on the second page is TypeError: `document.getElementById(...) is null`, which refers to the first bit of code in the JS file that is not present on the 2nd page

Thanks for your time

Comment: The script likely stops because of an error because you're trying to get `innerHTML` on null. Check you console.

Comment: The script works fine on the 1st page, the "p.classes" is not present on the 2nd page. Therefore I get the null error

Comment: In short you are saying use a different Javascript file for each page, or put a "p.classes" on each page?

Comment: No we are saying check your return value to make sure it isnt null, ie `if(document.querySelector("p.classes") != null){ ... }`

Comment: Ah I see. I will have to try that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery silently "fails" for these situations. If it doesn't find a selector it just returns an empty jQuery object that you can still call methods from, though they wont do anything.

Example

```js
jQuery('NonExistentElement').html("won't show up")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
No error will be thrown.
```

Native DOM methods like `querySelector()` don't return an empty object that you can still access methods from. They will either return the element, a list of elements (NodeList,HTMLCollection, etc) or null. Thus if you try to access a property on a return value from one of these you have a potential for failure in the case of a null return

```js
document.querySelector('NonExistentElement').innerHTML = "Won't show up";
```

This is why you need to check for `null` before trying to use it

```js
var element = document.querySelector('p.classes');
if(element != null){
   element.innerHTML = "your html";
}
var element2 = document.querySelector('p.classes2');
if(element2 != null){
   element2.innerHTML = "no error as the if statement fails and so this code wont execute";
}
```

```html
<p class="classes"></p>
```